# JSON appearing as PHP array without using json_decode()

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using jstree on a project and attempting to save my tree to a database.

I'm obtaining the tree data as follows:

```
var tmp = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_json();
console.log(tmp);
```

This produces a JSON object in the console as I'd expect:

[image]

However when I post this to a PHP script using jquery...

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/saveTree',
    data: {'tree': tmp},
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  });
```

... It is showing a PHP array of my data:

[image]

The script which I have at `/saveTree` displays the POST data in the `tree` array post key:

```
var_dump($this->request->data['tree']);
```

I assumed since the data I'm posting to the script is in JSON format I'd need to `json_decode()` it at the other end? If not, why not?

I've also tried adding `dataType: 'json',` in the ajax request but that makes no difference.

What's happening here?

*Please note the PHP script at `/saveTree` is running in CakePHP 2.x so the line of PHP above is equivalent to `var_dump($_POST['tree'])` in regular PHP.*

Comment: Cake will automatically decode JSON when the incoming request has the proper `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Ok... do you mean if I put `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax request? Because it seems to be doing exactly the same thing with or without that. That's why I was confused!

Comment: Furthermore `Content-Type:text/html;` is showing in Chrome's Network tab when making the request to `/saveTree`

Comment: `Content-Type:text/html` on the request, or the response?

Comment: Ah my bad, i was looking at the Response. The Request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` irrespective of whether `dataType` has been specified in the ajax call. Is that normal?

Comment: In that case, your data's being posted as if it were a bunch of `<input>` fields in a `<form>` tag. Same sort of result, different mechanism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159907/discussion-between-andy-and-ceejayoz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want send the data as string you can `JSON.stringify(tmp);`

```
 tmp = JSON.stringify(tmp);

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/saveTree',
    data: {'tree': tmp},
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I want to send it as JSON. It appears as JSON when I do the initial `console.log`. Please have a read over the comments (including chat) on the original post. Something weird is going on because it's being "changed" from JSON to some kind of form data representation and I cannot understand why. The original JSON in the first `console.log` is what I want...and then to `json_decode()` it in PHP on the receiving end?

Comment: Do you want to receive it as a string on php? or associative array?

Comment: If you send it on ajax on a json format, you will receive that on php as a an associative array.

Comment: If you want a json structure eg `{ val1 : 1, val2 : 3 }`, then you have to convert it to string, send it as a string. So that when you receive it on php.. It has the same structure. Im not sure if thats what you need though.

Comment: You can convert associative array to json format by `json_encode`

Comment: Another way of asking my question is - why do I *not* have to use `json_decode()` because the data being sent is in JSON format? That's what I don't understand. It's JSON when sent in the ajax request `data: {'tree': tmp},` but when it arrives in PHP (at `/saveTree`) it's all of a sudden been converted to a PHP array. Someone mentioned CakePHP may be doing this automatically, but I don't know. Is there any circumstance where `json_decode()` would be used here, or have I got this completely wrong?

Comment: This is not only on `CakePHP`. This how it works on `php`, even on custom `php` scripts. If you send it as a json you don't need to `json_decode`..

Comment: Ok, in that case it works according to my needs I guess. I didn't understand this initially so thanks for clarifying it. I thought that because the data was in JSON format during the request, it had to be `json_decode()`'d at the other end for PHP to get it into an array. If PHP does this automatically that's great.

Comment: You will only need to `json_decode` if you convert it to string (Like my asnwer) and send it.